# file format not recognized; treating as linker script - Compiling c code for arm processor

Tags: c, linux, arm

I am struggling to compile a demo program for an arm device.

Documentation is non-existant and I more used to a Windows environment.

I have installed and try on Ubuntu 14 and 13.10, but have the same problem in both. Both are 32 bit.

The makefile is as such:

```
#
# program makefile for the POS Application
#

# build on arm-linux platform
ARCH    = /opt/gcc-4.0.2-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnu-

# programs we use...
CP  = cp -f
MKDIR   = mkdir -p
RM  = rm -f
RMDIR   = rm -rf
TAR = tar -zcf
STRIP   = $(ARCH)strip
RANLIB  = $(ARCH)ranlib

# compiler names:
CC      = $(ARCH)gcc
CXX     = $(ARCH)g++

# flags for C/C++ compiler:
INCFLAG     = -I../include -I../sdk/include
OPTIM       = -Wall -O2 -Wunused
CFLAGS      = $(OPTIM)
CXXFLAGS    = $(OPTIM) -Wno-non-virtual-dtor

# libraries to link with:
LD_LIBS     = -ldl -lrt
LD_SDK      = -L../sdk -lkfsdk

LDFLAGS     = $(LD_LIBS) $(LD_SDK)

# Which targets should be built?
TARGET  = demo_app
#RELEASEDIR = ../release

# Be quiet when building...
#.SILENT:

#
# Files for this directory...
#
SRCDIR  = ../src

PATH1       = $(SRCDIR)/gui/
PATH2       = $(SRCDIR)/platform/

COBJECT     = \
        $(addprefix $(PATH1), $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(notdir $(wildcard $(PATH1)*.c))))) \
        $(addprefix $(PATH2), $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(notdir $(wildcard $(PATH2)*.c))))) \

CPPOBJECT   = \
        $(addprefix $(PATH1), $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(notdir $(wildcard $(PATH1)*.cxx))))) \
        $(addprefix $(PATH2), $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(notdir $(wildcard $(PATH2)*.cxx))))) \

#CFILES     = $(wildcard *.c)
#COBJECT    = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(CFILES))
#CPPFILES   = $(wildcard *.cxx)
#CPPOBJECT  = $(patsubst %.cxx, %.o, $(CPPFILES))

#
# Make everything...
#
all:    $(TARGET)
#   $(CP) $(TARGET) $(RELEASEDIR)
    @echo "All files have been made"
    @echo "            ************************************"
    @echo "            *                                  *"
    @echo "            *       POS APPLICATION      *"
    @echo "            *                                  *"
    @echo "            ************************************"
    @echo "succeed"

$(TARGET):  $(COBJECT) $(CPPOBJECT)
    @echo Linking $(TARGET)...
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
#   $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)

%.o:%.c
    @echo Compiling $<...
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCFLAG) -o $@ -c $<

%.o:%.cxx
    @echo Compiling $<...
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCFLAG) -o $@ -c $<

#
# Clean old files...
#
clean:
    $(RM) *.o
    $(RM) $(PATH1)*.o
    $(RM) $(PATH2)*.o
    $(RM) $(TARGET)

#
# End of "$Id: Makefile 2011-01-24 08:21 $".
#
# DO NOT DELETE
```

I have run make clean, and then make and get the following message:

```
Compiling ../src/platform/main.c...
/opt/gcc-4.0.2-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -Wall -O2 -Wunused -I../include -I../sdk/include -o ../src/platform/main.o -c ../src/platform/main.c
Linking demo_app...
/opt/gcc-4.0.2-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -o demo_app ../src/platform/main.o -Wall -O2 -Wunused -ldl -lrt -L../sdk -lkfsdk
/opt/gcc-4.0.2-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/4.0.2/../../../../arm-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld:/opt/gcc-4.0.2-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/4.0.2/../../../../arm-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libdl.so: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/opt/gcc-4.0.2-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld:/opt/gcc-4.0.2-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/4.0.2/../../../../arm-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libdl.so:1: parse error
collect2: ld return 1 exit status.
```

From the googling I have done, it seems to be a problem linking the files together, but I have no idea why and what is wrong.

I have tried apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi

The /opt/gcc-4.0.2-glibc-2.3.5 directory and subdirectories came with the so called SDK supplied for the the device.

Any ideas as to how to get this working?

Thank you

Neill

Edit 1:

If I do a more on `libdl.so`, it shows `libdl.s0.2`. If I more that file, it gives `libdl-2.3.5.so`. And finally if i do a `readelf -h libdl-2.3.5.so` that file, I get:

```
ELF 

    Header:
      Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 61 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
      Class:                             ELF32
      Data:                              2's complement, little endian
      Version:                           1 (current)
      OS/ABI:                            ARM
      ABI Version:                       0
      Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
      Machine:                           ARM
      Version:                           0x1
      Entry point address:               0xc78
      Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
      Start of section headers:          9864 (bytes into file)
      Flags:                             0x2, has entry point, GNU EABI
      Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
      Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
      Number of program headers:         7
      Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
      Number of section headers:         32
      Section header string table index: 29
```

Id I do `file libdl-2.3.5.so` I get:

```
/opt/gcc-4.0.2-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libdl-2.3.5.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, version 1, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.4.3, not stripped
```

I edited here because of the long post.

Neill

Comment: I cannot help much, but there is something wrong when you call the linker : It tries to use a library `.so` file (the Linux equivalent of Windows `.dll` files) and interpret it as a linker script. Of course this does not work. You'd want to double check how the linker is called on the command line within your makefile.

Comment: kindly paste `readelf -h /path/to/libdl.so`

Comment: readelf: Error: /opt/gcc-4.0.2-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/lib//libdl.so: Failed to read file header

Comment: Please see Edit 1 on original post

Comment: in the makefile, probably should use ':=' rather than '=' when creating the macros, so the macro is not re-evaluated each time it is invoked.

Comment: there should NOT be a '\' at the end of the last line of a multi line macro definition

Comment: near the top of the makefile, the line: '.PHONY: all clean' is needed

Comment: To properly re-compile when a header file is updated, the list of header files needs to be a part of such lines as %.o:%,c dependencies   This us usually handled by making use of the appropriate parameters by invokation of the gcc compiler to produce the dependency files, (although 'sed' can do the same thing)

Comment: this kind of line: ' $(addprefix $(PATH1), $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(notdir $(wildcard $(PATH1)*.c)))))' would be better written as: CSRC := $(wildcard $(PATH1)/*.c) $(wildcard $(PATH2)/*.c) COBJECT := $(CSRC: .c=.o) and similarly for the .c++ files   Amongst other things, gcc does not know where to find a source file that is not in the current directory, so need to include the path to that file.  also,  suggest placing the object files in the same directory as the source, then passing the full paths to the linker

Comment: What do you mean with "If I do a more on libdl.so, it shows libdl.s0.2. If I more that file, it gives libdl-2.3.5.so."? Are you saying the content of `libdl.so` is the string  "`libdl.s0.2`"? That certainly would be wrong.

Comment: In your error messages the following partial path is given in your post: `../arm-unknown-inux=gnu/lib/libdl.so`.  That doesn't look correct - is it a typo or a copy/paste error? (if so, please fix it)  Or if that is actually in the error message then your toolchain installation may be corrupted since it should probably say `../arm-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libdl.so`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example make file,
It includes the creation and usage of dependency files
for included header files.
It uses 'sed' for generation of the dependency files.
In general, it expects all the files to be in the 
local directory, so you will need to modify it for
your multiple source file directories, etc

```
SHELL = /bin/sh


BINDIR  :=  /home/user/bin


.PHONY: all
all : $(BINDIR)/$(name) 


#
# macro of all *.c files 
# (NOTE:
# (the following 'wildcard' will pick up ALL .c files
# (like FileHeader.c and FunctionHeader.c 
# (which should not be part of the build
# (so be sure no unwanted .c files in directory
# (or change the extension
#
SRC := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ := $(SRC:.c=.o)
DEP := $(SRC:.c=.d)
INC := $(SRC:.c=.h)


MAKE    :=  /usr/bin/make

CC      :=  /usr/bin/gcc

CP      :=  cp

MV      := mv

LDFLAGS :=  -L/usr/local/lib

DEBUG   :=  -ggdb3

CCFLAGS :=  $(DEBUG) -Wall -W

# pre processor flags, not C++ flags
#CPPFLAGS += =MD


LIBS    :=   -lssl -ldl -lrt -lz -lc -lm



#
# link the .o files into the executable 
# using the linker flags
# -- explicit rule
#
$(name): $(OBJ) $(COMMON_OBJ) ../makefile.mak ../makefile.bot
    #
    # ======= $(name) Link Start =========
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJ) $(COMMON_OBJ) $(LIBS)
    # ======= $(name) Link Done ==========
    #



# note:
# using MV rather than CP results in all executables being re-made everytime
$(BINDIR)/$(name): $(name)
    #
    # ======= $(name) Copy Start =========
    sudo $(CP) $(name) $(BINDIR)/.
    # ======= $(name) Copy Done ==========
    #



#
#create dependancy files -- inference rule
# list makefile.mak as dependancy so changing makfile forces rebuild
#
%.d: %.c 
    # 
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$;                      \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@;     \
    rm -f $@.$$$$
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========



# 
# compile the .c file into .o files using the compiler flags
# -- inference rule
#
%.o: %.c %.d 
    # 
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I. 
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========
    # 



.PHONY: clean
clean: 
    # ========== CLEANING UP ==========
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(name).map
    rm -f $(name)
    rm -f *.d
    # ========== DONE ==========




# include the contents of all the .d files
# note: the .d files contain:
# <filename>.o:<filename>.c plus all the dependancies for that .c file 
# I.E. the #include'd header files
# wrap with ifneg... so will not rebuild *.d files when goal is 'clean'
#
ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
-include $(DEP)
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

First off apologies for taking long to get back to this, had a bad flu and stayed in bed.

I finally figured out what was going on and it turns out it was something simple, as it often is.

The SDK for the arm device came with GCC that was put under /opt. It turns out for some unknown reason the copy I had, had been untar'd, but had lost all links under /opt/gcc-4.0.2-glibc-2.3.5/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/lib directory.

Thanks to undur_gongor, your comment made me look closer at those files and I managed to find the original .tar.bz2 file, untar'd it to the correct directory and all the links where there and it compiled fine.

Neill